# How do I fix TypeError in Python

Tags: python, pandas

It shows the following error

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Here is the code

```
data.loc[(data['Account'] == Value) & (data['Contract End Month'] >= 7),
             'End Fiscal Year'] = data['Contract End Year'] + 1
```

Comment: One of your concatenations concatenates an int and a string, I would guess thats the `data['Contract End Year'] + 1`, to fix this use: `data['Contract End Year'] + str(1)` but thats probably not what you are trying to achieve here ... anyway know you can convert that way

Comment: data['Contract End Year'] is probably of the wrong type, add `data.show()` to your post

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `data['Contract End Year']` is an `str` instance, try casting it into an `int` before performing the addition:

```
data.loc[(data['Account'] == Value) & (data['Contract End Month'] >= 7),'End Fiscal Year'] = int(data['Contract End Year']) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is indicating that you are trying to concatenate a string with an integer.
It seems like the column 'Contract End Year' is of type string, but you're trying to add 1 to it as if it were an integer.
You can convert it to int using pandas.to_numeric method and then adding 1, and later you can convert it back to str

```
data['Contract End Year'] = pd.to_numeric(data['Contract End Year'], errors='coerce')
data.loc[(data['Account'] == Value) & (data['Contract End Month'] >= 7),
             'End Fiscal Year'] = data['Contract End Year'] + 1
data['End Fiscal Year'] = data['End Fiscal Year'].astype(str)
```

This should fix the TypeError and allow you to perform the arithmetic operation on the 'Contract End Year' column.